# Unable to get realtime database in recyclerview of the fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get data in recyclerview of fragment from realtime database.

Here is the code of Home Fragment I used to get data from realtime database:-

```
class HomeFragments : Fragment() {

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var typesAdapter: SU_Types_adapter? = null
    private var type: MutableList<SU_Type_Model>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView = rv_home_fragment
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)

        type = ArrayList()
        typesAdapter = activity?.let { SU_Types_adapter(it, type as ArrayList<SU_Type_Model>, true) }
        recyclerView?.adapter = typesAdapter

        val typesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SU_Types").orderByChild("type")
        typesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    typesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    val su_type = snapshot.getValue(SU_Type_Model::class.java)
                    if (su_type != null) {
                        (type as ArrayList<SU_Type_Model>)?.add(su_type)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragments, container, false)
    }
}
```

Here is the adapter code that I use to get the database data:-

```
class SU_Types_adapter(
    private var mContext: Context,
    private var mTypes: List<SU_Type_Model>,
    private var isActivity: Boolean = false
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SU_Types_adapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_home_fragment_adapter, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val su_type = mTypes[position]

        Picasso.get().load(su_type.getImageUrl()).into(holder.ImageIv)
        holder.ImgId.text = su_type.gettype()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mTypes.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var ImageIv: ImageView? = itemView.su_type_iv
        var ImgId: TextView = itemView.su_type_tv

    }
}
```

Here is the model code:-

```
class SU_Type_Model {

    private var ImageUrl: String = ""
    private var type: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(
        ImageUrl: String,
        type: String
    ) {
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
        this.type = type
    }


    fun getImageUrl(): String {
        return ImageUrl
    }

    fun setImageUrl(ImageUrl: String) {
        this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl
    }

    fun gettype(): String {
        return type
    }

    fun settype(type: String) {
        this.type = type
    }
}
```

here is snapshot of [database image.][image: database image]

json file code is:-

```
{
  "SU_Types": {
    "asdfadsfa": {
      "ImageUrl": "\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehi-10.appspot.com/o/Types%2FAdvertising%2F1113-lalbaugcha-raja-wallpaper-07.jpg?alt=media&token=c2d78337-e66b-43cf-bed5-8e65cf94c342\"",
      "type": "\"sing\""
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to get the data in activity using similar code but I am unable to get the data in Fragment. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added screenshot of the database.

Comment: I dont know how to add file in the question but I have added code of the json file.

Comment: Have you tried to move the `typesAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` right after the for loop ends?

Comment: I tried but it is not working.

Comment: "it is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I am unable to get data. There is no error. Now I just saw that constructor of the model is never used. In earlier cases it was used but I don't know why I am unable to use constructor.

Comment: In logcat I am getting this:- "RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: recyclerView = rv_home_fragment.
 this is the mistake you are doing. You don't give recyclerView references that's why you are getting errors. Better to debug the code and check recyclerView is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of activity use context:-

```
  recyclerView?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)

typesAdapter = context?.let { SU_Types_adapter(it, type as ArrayList<SU_Type_Model>, true) }
```

and make changes for getting recyclerview:-

```
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_home_fragment)
```